# How to filter values in a doc library

Tags: list, document-library, column, filter

I have a doc library with let say 200 documents and two category so if i in the first category that is called Doc category i choose Devices then i want in the next column that is called Category type only to how the relevant categorys like printers computers etc and last whne you choose device i want to see document that is relveant to the category type.

```
Doc Category                          Category Type
Manuals if this is choosen only view: Instalation, summary etc         
Devices if this is choosen only view: Servers, Router, Firewall etc
Network if this is choosen only view: wlan, vla, vpn etc
```

Comment: I'll suggest to create different views based on different criteria and hope that will serve the purpose.

Comment: ok will try that thansks

Answer (score -4):

you can use tags that are available in SharePoint for document libraries

kindly go through the below link you could find it helpful

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Use-tags-and-notes-to-share-information-with-colleagues-18e87002-a0bb-473f-9959-358f42be8d03

Comment: We looking a detailed answer, link only anwser bad.